# If i have 3 same bodies, all have different temperatures. How i can get max temperature for some body?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature

I have 3 identical bodies with temperatures $T_1 < T_2 < T_3$. I have working mass, so I can use the Carnot cycle. For example, with the first two bodies, I can extract work equal to $C(\sqrt T_2 - \sqrt T_1 )^2$, where $C$ is the heat capacity. Using this work, I can heat the third body, but do other ways exist to obtain a higher temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first law of thermodynamics applied to this problem says that the sum of the 3 temperatures must remain the same. The maximum possible temperature follows from the second law, the entropy will in the best case stay the same (suppose that someone claims that some final state is optimal but this has a larger entropy than the initial state, then you can construct a state with the same entropy as the initial state by increasing the temperature of the hottest object and decreasing the temperature of some other object). This means that the product of the temperatures will stay the same. As long as the temperatures of all the bodies except one are not equal, there is always room to extract work from these bodies and dump the energy to the body with the highest temperature while keeping the entropy the same. So, from the initial state we find $c_1$ and $c_2$:

$$
\begin{split}
c_1 &= T_1 + T_2 + T_3\\
c_2 &= T_1 T_2 T_3
\end{split}
$$

The temperature $T_3'$ of the hottest body in the final state and the temperature $T_1'$ of the two coldest bodies can then be solved from the equations:

$$
\begin{split}
2 T_1'+ T_3' = c_1\\
T_1'^2 T_3' = c_2
\end{split}
$$

This yields a cubic equation for $T_3'$.

Comment: sorry, it appears that I was typing while you were...

Comment: @CoiThank u for answering, i'm trying to get answer on wolframalpha for 300K,350K,400K, but get complex root, what does it means?

Comment: @Gorogorov There will be one real solution for $T_3'$ the equations but it is a solution of a cubic equation and cubic equations always have 3 solutions in the complex plane. Now a cubic equation with real coefficients will always have one real solution or 3 real solution (counting with multiplicities).  In this case you'll thus have two complex solution and one real solution.

Comment: @hyportnex No problem , the more solutions posted the better!

Comment: @Count Iblis, sorry, i can't understand why entropy must be the same. Search in internet, but still can't understand. Could you explain please (sorry for bad english)

Comment: @Gorogorov The entropy of a closed system can only increase or it can be the same, it can never decrease. We also know that dumping a small amount of heat $dQ$ in a body at temperature $T$ causes the entropy to increase by $dQ/T$. A transfer of heat of $dQ$ from a body of temperature $T_1$ to another body of temperature $T_2$ this causes the total entropy to change by $dS = \left(1/T_2 - 1/T_1\right)dQ$. So, if  $T_2 < T_1$ then this exchange leads to entropy increase. The opposite process where heat would low from cold to hot would lead to entropy decrease.

Comment: Then if you have some final state where the entropy has increased, then even though you cannot physically get to a lower entropy state anymore, you can still say that if you were to move energy to the hottest object from a colder object then the entropy of the new state would be lower. So, you can construct on paper a state that satisfies all the conditions (same internal energy and entropy at least as high as in the initial state) but in which the temperature of the hottest body is higher. This proves that any solution where the entropy has increased is not optimal.

Comment: The conclusion is therefore that the entropy must remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in Callen, Section 4.1 as follows. Let the final high temperature be $T_h$. The two lower temperature bodies will have the same temperature, say $T_c$, otherwise more reversible work could be extracted with the Carnot engine and then the work inserted back back to warm the hot body. Now energy conservation demands that
 $$T_h+2T_c = T_1+T_2+T_3=T_0 \tag{1}$$, at the same time the total entropy change is
$$\begin{align}\Delta S = C \text{ln}\left(\frac{T_c}{T_1}\right)  C \text{ln}\left(\frac{T_c}{T_2}\right) + C \text{ln}\left(\frac{T_h}{T_3}\right)
 \\ = C \text{ln}\left(\frac{T_c^2T_h}{T_1T_2T_3}\right) \end{align} \tag{2}$$

For this to be positive we must have $\frac{T_c^2T_h}{T_1T_2T_3} \ge 1. \tag{3}$ Now eliminate $T_c$ from $(3)$ using $(1)$ 
$$ \frac{1}{4}(T_0-T_h)^2 T_h \ge T_1T_2T_3. \tag{4}$$
We have to find the largest $T_h$ for which the inequality $(4)$ still holds. This of course leads to finding the solutions of the cubic $$ \frac{1}{4}(T_0-x)^2 x =  T_1T_2T_3. \tag{5}$$ whose largest positive root is the sought $T_h$